# Test object with filesystem functions

Tags: php, unit-testing, filesystems, integration-testing

I'm writing some objects which make extensive use of the filesystem. I'm not sure what is the right way to test them.

I know in theory I should abstract filesystem functionality in some objects and then mock them, but it would be quite pointless in my case: the main use of the classes I want to test is to manage files. So I would have the same problem when testing the new objects, just shifted one level.

The only way I can think to make the tests is to actually work with the filesystem. The problem is that tests will be ran both in the browser and on the command line, and so I need to work in a directory with write access by everyone. Moreover, this does not seem to be a very portable solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [mock the filesystem with vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) as [suggested in the PHPUnit Manual](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem):

> vfsStream is a stream wrapper for a virtual file system that may be helpful in unit tests to mock the real file system […] If the PEAR installer is available on your system, you only need to execute the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ pear channel-discover pear.bovigo.org
> $ pear install bovigo/vfsStream-beta
> ```

There is [examples at Github](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/tree/master/examples) and also a [Wiki](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki)

Comment: 'Hah - you're a rubbish file system. The last file system I had was much better than you, lol'. That kind of mocking? ;)

Comment: The PHPUnit documentation is incomplete. Is there a better reference? It's missing information on how to mock the filesystem (as in simulate that a file exists, specify the simulated file's contents, etc.)

Comment: @dpk there is [examples at Github](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/tree/master/examples) and also a [Wiki](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki)

Comment: Thanks, I looked those over earlier but was still stumped. Finally hit on the piece I was missing: vfsStream only abstracts files referred to with the prefix "vfs://". In retrospect, that is obvious, but I was trying all sorts of things trying to get it to work with bare files (e.g. "/usr/local/blah/blah.txt"). Hopefully this comment will help future folks.

Comment: Sadly [vfsStream does not support everything](http://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki/Known-Issues). It seems like glob() not working is going to be the dealbreaker for me :(.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce very low level php functions that do nothing other than call file system functions, and use these within your code.

Then, in your test harness, override this functions with stubs (that possibly record that they've been called). That way you can verify that your code will, in the live system, call the correct low level PHP functions. For a unit test thats all you can do, really.

Comment: The original question does not mention unit testing, this appears to be specifically an integration related question. i would have thought that mocking anything would undermine the purpose of the tests?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have three options:

- Accept that some tests are better off as Integration Tests. Start the test by creating a little world for the test to run in (in %TEMP%, based on the class/method name) then destroy it when you are done.
- Examine you layer of abstraction, and extract the file IO from the class. The create a interface for this. The remainder use integration tests (but this will be very small). This differs from above in that instead of doing file.Read you write the intent, say ioThingie.loadSettings().
- Mock the IO (as suggested by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400366/test-object-with-filesystem-functions/4400400#4400400) above).

I normally go with a mix of options one and two and only use three for edge cases as I find in C# mocking the raw IO layer (System.IO.File) really only shows you can write mocking statements, and makes your test a little too dependent on the implementation, however the vfs above looks like it mocks the FS, rather than a the objects.

Comment: The problem is that my objects mainly deal with the filesystem, and there is not much to test if I move the filesystem functions in the Integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is to mock PHP functions that use file system with [runkit](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit). Not sure it is the best solution but it works.
There is [phpunit-mockfunction](https://github.com/tcz/phpunit-mockfunction) - PHPUnit extension that simplifies mocking PHP functions.

So example is:

```
class Tests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    // ... setUp, tearDown, other tests...

    function test_1(){
        $file_size_to_return = 10;

        $fake_filesize = new PHPUnit_Extensions_MockFunction('filesize', $this->obj->tested_method);
        $fake_filesize->expects($this->once())->will($this->returnValue($file_size_to_return));

        $this->obj->tested_method(); // actually run method we want test that contains filesize() function...
    }
}
```